# What is 'the game' mean here? From "Chicago , 2002"

Tags: cinema

The script is from "Chicago, 2002". I have a few questions. Thank you.

Q1. In the last paragraph, I don't understand the sentence grammatically.

Is the sentence same as:  *the assistant D.A. promises the game (that) IittIe sharpshooter wiII swing before the year is up.* ?

Why is it 'the game'?

Who is 'little sharpshooter'?

What does 'swing' mean here?

Why is Harrison gonna be governor?

> A voice from news: The Windy City has taken a new criminaI to its
>   heart. The name on everybody's Iips is Roxie Hart.
>
> The sweetest IittIe Iady ever accused of murder in Chicago. Women want
>   to Iook Iike her. FeIIas want to go out with her. Some IittIe girIs
>   even want to take her home. Don't get any ideas, IittIe Iady.
>
> On the other side of town . . . the assistant D.A. promises ***the game***
>   ***IittIe sharpshooter*** wiII ***swing*** before the year is up. Who knows? If he
>   Iives up to his word , Assistant D.A. Harrison might become Governor
>   Harrison someday.

Q2. What does "stiffs" mean here?

> Mama: So, kiddo, given any thought to what you want to do after BiIIy
>   gets you off?
>
> Roxie: I think I'd Iike to go on the stage.
>
> Mama: I figured as much . I aIready caIIed the Morris office.
>
> Roxie: ReaIIy? How much is that gonna cost me?
>
> Mama: My standard deaI.
>
> Roxie: Yeah , well , we'II see, Mama. Besides, I don't even have an
>   act yet.
>
> Mama: KiIIing Fred CaseIy was your act. Those ***stiffs*** in the
>   audience want to say they saw somebody famous.
>
> Roxie: That's a freak act.

And why is Mama saying those stiffs want to say thay saw somebody famous?

Comment: *Game* is an adjective here, look it up. *LittIe sharpshooter* refers to the Roxie Hart character. *Swing* means she will be hanged (i.e. sentenced to death).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-parsing the phrase.

'Game' is here an adjective meaning 'ready to try something difficult' or perhaps 'plucky'. 'Little' has it's obvious meaning and 'sharpshooter' means one who fires a gun accurately, specifically Roxie who killed her boyfriend. 'swing' means to hang.

So the meaning is that the DA has promised to make sure the plucky woman who shot the man hangs for the crime.

DA (District Attorney) is often a post chosen by ambitious lawyers who want to be elected to higher office, such as governor. Their chances of being elected to governor often depend on their success on getting convictions on high profile criminals like murderers.

'Stiff' is a somewhat derogatory term for a person. Sometimes it can mean a member of the working class, general not-very-sophisticated person or vagrant.